# JavaScript/PHP: Alert dialog after successfully saved

Tags: javascript, php, html

I new in programming. Currently, I develop a system that registration part. The registration part is successfully saved to the database. What I want to know is how to popup an alert dialog with one button e.g "Ok" after registration was successful and redirect to another page, such as home page. Now I only echo "successfully saved"

Below is my current code

```
<?php
require "DbConnect.php";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $badgeid = $_POST['badgeid'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $department = $_POST['department'];
    $factory = $_POST['factory'];
    $reviewer = $_POST['reviewer'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $suggestionwill = $_POST['suggestionwill'];
    $present = $_POST['present'];
    $details = $_POST['details'];
    $benefit = $_POST['benefit'];


$sql_query = "INSERT INTO topsuggest (name,badgeid,position,department,factory,
reviewer,title,year,month,suggestionwill,present,details,benefit) VALUES('$name','$badgeid','$position','$department','$factory','$reviewer','$title','$year','$month','$suggestionwill','$present','$details','$benefit')";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query))
{
echo "<p id='msg'></p>";
}
else
{
echo "Error!! Not Saved".mysqli_error($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: You can do it with an ajax-request. Stop the default event on submit your form and use JS to show your ajax-message. E.g.: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ or https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html or look at the pure js https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_examples.asp request. And take care you will escape your variables in your sql string https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use php header and use javascript to alert a message .

```
      if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query))
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Successfuly Saved');</script>";
 header('Location: PATH TO BE REDIRECTED');
    }
```

For a example

```
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query))
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Successfuly Saved');</script>";
 header('Location: ../Insert/Index.php');
    }
```

**Please note that space between Location:  is compulsory**

Comment: Here is no "dialog" with an "OK" button, wich you will forward to an other page.

Comment: @Richard yes you are correct.So that I have updated my answer.Thanks .

Comment: @F.Lampard if you found an answer please mark it as a answer.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After inserting data you can simply redirect to your interested page with a success message like:

```
header("location:page_of_interest.php?msg=Record Inserted");
```

and on `page_of_interest.php` you can simply check for msg and show if it is set like:

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
  echo $_GET['msg'];
}
```